# How to determine minimum time required to update a peer server bounded in master-master replication in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, replication

I was looking onto a Database Design and Master - Master Replication was proposed for it. Basically there will be two MSSQL servers ; say ALPHA and BETA.

This replication method is applied where any of the servers could be used at times to update data from application; regardless of hierarchy, which was there in traditional Master Slave replication.

**Is there a way to find the minimum time required to propagate the change to BETA server once data modification occurs in ALPHA?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your network, which can be a significant performance bottleneck.  Microsoft recommends a fast network of 100 Mbps or faster in [Enhance General Replication Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151791.aspx).

A test environment should be setup simulating your network(s) to establish a latency baseline.  Peer-to-Peer Replication operates in near real time so the amount of latency should be low.

Answer (score 0):

I had it checked and found that it takes 1 second in minimum to replicate data from a server to another peer during master-master replication.

Thanks.